# insert multiple a una tabla en wordpress

Tags: php, mysql

en el codigo adjunto se muestra como hago un insert por codigo en wordpress, lo que necesito es hacer varios insert a la misma tabla, pero la informacion esta en textbox diferentes, lo que necesito es poder hacer varios insert en una sola consulta sin usar for, while o DoWhile

```
$sql11 = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `$tablename11` (`identificacion_interesado`,`id_nivel_ed`,`año_inicio`,`año_final`,`nombre_instituto`,`grado_recivido`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
,$documentoidentidad,$nivel_educa,$iniciosecunda,$finsecunda,$nombresecunda,$gradosecunda); 
$success11=$wpdb->query($sql11);
```

Comment: Y como queres traer los valores de cada campo de texto?

Comment: @gbianchi$nombresecunda=$_POST['nombresecunda'];
 $finsecunda=$_POST['finsecunda'];
 $iniciosecunda=$_POST['iniciosecunda'];
 $gradosecunda=$_POST['gradosecunda'];

Comment: No entiendo nada.. ahi traes el valor de cada uno de esos campos.. que otros campos queres?

Comment: Puedes insertar varias filas siguiente [la técnica explicada en esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374838/5587982). Si no lo logras, debes exponer el problema con mayor claridad y te ayudaremos. La pregunta no es clara.

Comment: @A.Cedano bien debo insertar los siguientes campos: <input type="text" name="nombtecn" id="nombtecn" class="form-control">
<select name="iniciotecn" id="iniciotecn"  class="form-control"> <?php for($anio=(date("Y")); 1950<=$anio; $anio--) {echo "<option value=".$anio.">".$anio."</option>";}?></select>
<select name="fintecn" id="fintecn" class="form-control"> <?php for($anio=(date("Y")); 1950<=$anio; $anio--) {echo "<option value=".$anio.">".$anio."</option>";}?></select>
<input type="text" name="gradotecn" id="gradotecn" class="form-control">

Comment: @A.Cedano se que puede hacer otra sentencia de insercion pero lo que necesito es poder en una sola sentecia de insercion insetar lo que serian varias filas de una tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: "sin usar for, while o DoWhile" Pues hasta donde yo se de PHP solo te queda each() y no te garantizo que puedas llegar a sacar algo. El no usar esas estructuras de control es por algún tipo de problema con wordpress?